# sort two columns by value edited

Tags: c#

```
form.myDataTable.Rows[i][2 * cs] = corr;                
form.myDataTable.Rows[i][2 * cs + 1] = "p" + Convert.ToString(col1) 
                                        + " p" + Convert.ToString(col2);
```

I need to sort `2*cs` column by values and also corresponding names in column `2*cs+1`.

I am trying like this:

```
var corrvalues = new Dictionary(); 
correlationvalues["p" + Convert.ToString(col1) 
                      + " p" + Convert.ToString(col2)] = corr;
sortedvalues = correlationvalues.Values.OrderByDescending;
```

I am not clear how to use orderbydescending, i am new to c#. Thanks for help.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: OK, got that. Thank You John and Thank You Mark, i am new to this forum. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OrderByDescending is a function, not a property.  It has one required parameter, which is a function that takes a value in the collection (in your case, `correctionvalues.Values`) and returns a "key" to use for comparison purposes.  If you just want to compare directly on the values themselves, you can pass in an identity lambda function (e.g. `x => x`).

```
var corrvalues = new Dictionary(); 
correlationvalues["p" + Convert.ToString(col1) 
                      + " p" + Convert.ToString(col2)] = corr;
sortedvalues = correlationvalues.Values.OrderByDescending(val => val);
```

If your values are more complex types (such as a `Person` class) and you want to sort on a particular field (such as `Name`), then you could pass in something like this:

```
sorted = personDict.Values.OrderByDescending(person => person.Name);
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending.aspx for more detail on OrderByDescending.

You can also learn more about lambda expressions (which is useful if you're new to C#) here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx